# Peristaltic pump design principles

Tags: pumps, vacuum-pumps

We're experimenting with 3D printed vacuum pumps, and a peristaltic pump is the leading contender, [being shown to reach pressures below 10^-1 Torr](https://avs.scitation.org/doi/pdf/10.1116/1.579988).

We don't know much about peristaltic pump design and are looking for references on pros and cons of various decisions. For instance, what are the effects of the following parameters?

- rotor diameter
- wheel diameter
- number of wheels
- strategies to address self-heating
- importance of manufacturing tolerances
- tubing material selection
- longevity of tubing (when pump is in motion)
- permanent creasing of tubing (when pump is unused)

Furthermore, are the specific design pitfalls for peristaltic pumps?

Comment: Have you found anything on Google?

Comment: @SolarMike No. Have you?

Comment: tltr: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peristaltic_pump